# OpenCV - documentation for CirclesGridFinder

Tags: opencv, camera, calibration

I am trying to use perform camera calibration using Asymmetric circles grid.
I can't find proper documentation for `CirclesGridFinder` in general, and in particular for `findHoles()` function.

I would appreciate if you have information on how this function works and what is the meaning of its parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenCV there is the findCirclesGrid() function that matches your description.
Maybe the documentation on this link will help you.
http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#findcirclesgrid